# Efficiently load pgpointcloud from PostGIS table values

Tags: pgpointcloud

Is it possible to efficiently load data into a pgpointcloud PCPatch table from an xyz type of table within the same database?

The github read me says - “Usually you will only be creating tables for storing PcPatch objects, and using PcPoint objects as transitional objects for filtering...”

And

“PostgreSQL Pointcloud storage of LIDAR works best when each "patch" of points consists of points that are close together, and when most patches do not overlap.”

So does this mean I should convert each individual xyz record to a PCPoint record, then convert n records to a patch? Window function?

Or should I create an array from the xyz records, then create a patch from the array?

I’m not sure what the most efficient/effective way to undertake this and ensure that the patches are made up of close together points.

Comment: What happens when you try to do this?

Comment: Yes, read the github doc.